# WKWebView with MoovWeb

Tags: ios, objective-c, uiwebview, wkwebview, moovweb

I have followed this blog and implemented WKWebView:

> http://gowithfloat.com/2014/12/one-webview-to-rule-them-all/

I am loading a page, which is coming through MoovWeb. So, the page will be responsive. But, instead of loading the responsive page from MoovWeb, my WKWebView is loading mobile site of the same URL. In UIWebView it is working fine and as expected.

How I can load a responsive page from MoovWeb into WKWebView?

Answer (score 0):

I believe what you are looking for is how to deliver static assets from Moovweb. If so, please check here for information on how to do this:
http://developer.moovweb.com/docs/cloud/static_asset_delivery

Juan C